# Updating a model from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to update the "User" model which has a column named "verification_code_confirmation" from the "Verifications" Controller

I had tried writing this code

```
   class VerificationController < ApplicationController

   def index
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success  => "Successfully verified." }
     else
       render :action => 'edit'
     end 
   end
```

and

index.html.erb for verifications view.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :verification_code_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :verification_code_confirmation %></div>

<% end %>
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :verification_code_confirmation, :phone

  end

end
```

I have updated to

```
 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

How do i do it? I have looked around in the internet to update my column through the verification controller but i couldn't.

Comment: Did you got any errors? Also if you want to update single column,try using `update_attribute` instead of `update_attributes`.

Comment: Couldn't find User without an ID

That is the error.

Comment: Well, what is being passed through as `params[:id]`? Evidently nothing?

Comment: yes. It passes nothing.